# Plot with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, chart.js

I had a Tkinter app built with Python and I would like to translate it in javascript using Chart.js to plot. Here is the picture of my Tkinter app :

[image: tkinter app]

And I need to have this button to change the values on some parameters like in the picture. How can I do this with Chart.js ?

Thank you.

Comment: Post some code showing what's happening

Comment: Actually in python I use this : `tk.Scale()` but I don't know the equivalent in js

Comment: And how the data is? As an Array? Some objects?